# Why doesn't my Samsung Galaxy S Captivate have self shot mode?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

I just bought my Samsung Galaxy S (Captivate).
My self shot mode is missing from the camera options. How do I get it? What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

The Captivate does not have a front-facing camera, thus no self-shot mode.  You'll have to turn it around and try to tap the on-screen button without seeing it to take a picture of yourself (or use a mirror, etc.).

Comment: For confirmation see this table that compares the features available in the different Galaxy S variants http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Comparison_Table