# Samsung Galaxy S front camera

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, front-camera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do with my front facing camera?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/what-can-i-do-with-my-front-facing-camera)

I have followed the directions and instructions from other users on here but, i have no "self shot" option nor do i have the camera with the arrows on my Galaxy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Other possible dupe http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/samsung-galaxy-s-captivate-self-shot-mode-missing From there you can see a link to a table showing which of the Galaxy S models have what features http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Comparison_Table

Answer (score 2):

Not all Galaxy S models have a front-facing camera.  Just (most?) GT-i9000's and Epic 4G's.  The Vibrant, Captivate, and Fascinate do not.

Comment: This link has a table showing which Galaxy S models have which features, including front cameras: http://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/index.php?title=Samsung_Galaxy_S_Series#Comparison_Table